# Performance Issues with Concurrent Queries During Mass Update in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I have a PostgreSQL table with a large amount of data (2 terabytes) where I recently performed a mass update to add UUID values to a column (uuid_column). While the update was successful, I am experiencing performance issues with concurrent queries.

Here are the steps I followed during the update:

```sql
-- Step 1: Add the id (uuid) column
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN  id  UUID;

-- Step 2: Add the column default, which only kicks in for new rows.
ALTER TABLE users
ALTER COLUMN uuid_column SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();

-- Step 3: Seed the uuid values
UPDATE users
SET uuid_column = uuid_generate_v4() WHERE uuid_column IS NULL;
```

After the update, running queries like

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uuid_column IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10;

-- OR
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uuid_column IS NOT NULL ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10;
```

tend to get stuck. But queries like below work,

```sql
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10;

-- OR
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10;
```

Also, the `VACUUM users` get stuck as well.

I suspect that the mass update has caused locking or contention issues. What could be the reasons for this performance problem, and how can I mitigate it?

Can `SELECT ...FOR UPDATE` help here?

Is there any way to optimize this mass update? Maybe tuning some server settings? OR adding more resources to server?

Also, please explain the reason, thanks.

I am using PostgreSQL 14.6 version.

Comment: If many rows have a NULL `uuid_column`, and you have no index on this column, those slow queries can be expected to be slow.

Comment: I have index on `timestamp` though, should it not affect?

Comment: If you use an index on `timestamp`, still many rows found with the index scan will have a NULL value for `uuid_column` and have to be disregarded. So that index scan would be slow as well.

Comment: None of these tasks should get stuck based on what you have described.  Some of them might just take longer than you would like, but that is a different thing.  Can you clarify what is actually happening?  Are they running (e.g. consuming resources in `top`) or are they not waiting on something and making no progress (which can find the wait even in pg_stat_activity).